# MathJax With Angular (5) and Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, mathjax

I'm learning Angular 5 and I'd like to pull some data out of my Firebase (done), display it in the webpage (done) and then render the maths using MathJax.

I have included MathJax in the header like so:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
        processEscapes: true
        }
});
```

This works fine for static data, but when I pull some data out of my Firebase it won't render. I know about components, but otherwise new to Angular. Could someone please help me with how I get the MathJax to render after AngularJS is done and so this would work live as the data in my Firebase changes, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using promise resolution? In your component, you could do for example:

```
.
.
.

declare var MathJax;

.
.
.

export class myComponent implements OnInit {

  firebaseDocRef = ...;
  myComponentProperty = ...;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit()
  {

    firebaseDocRef.get("key").then((data) =>
                           {
                             this.myComponentProperty = data;
                             MathJax.Hub.Queue(() => { MathJax.Hub.Typeset();});
                           });
  }

}
```